# Ruby's inject method like for Scala collections: any idea?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Scala

I have a

```
List( MyObject(id, name, status), ..., MyObject(id, name, status) )
```

and I want to apply a function to this collection in order to obtain a List containing all the "id" properties of MyObjects

```
List( id1, id2, .., idN)
```

I'd like something similar to Ruby's inject method:

```
list.inject( [] ){ |lst, el| lst << el }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `inject` is closest to `foldLeft`, but using inject with a list accumulator like that is a `map` so you might as well use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use List's (actually, TraversableLike's) map function, as follows: `list.map(_.id)`.
There are a wealth of useful methods like this available to the Scala collection classes - well worth learning.

Answer (score 2):

Using `list.map(_.id)` is the best solution in this case. Obviously, there are many other ways to do it. To put it into perspective, following are two examples.

### Injecting into an array

Adding selected elements into an array, e.g.:

```
    > list = [1,2,3]
     => [1,2,3]
    > list.inject([]) { |list,el| list << "Element #{el}"  if (el % 2 == 0); list }
     => ["Element 2"]
```

might be implemented in Scala as:

```
    > val list = List(1,2,3)
    list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
    > val map = list.map(x => if (x % 2 == 0) Some(s"Element $x") else None).flatten
    map: List[String] = List(Element 2)
```

### Injecting into a hash

Following Ruby code injecting into a hash:

```
    > list = [1,2,3]
     => [1,2,3]
    > list.inject({}) { |memo,x| memo[x] = "Element #{x}"; memo }
     => {1=>"Element 1", 2=>"Element 2", 3=>"Element 3"}
```

could be done in Scala as:

```
    > val list = List(1,2,3)
    list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
    > val map = list.map(x => (x -> s"Element $x")).toMap
    map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> Element 1, 2 -> Element 2, 3 -> Element 3)
```